# Django deserialize JSON request with nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I have the following Python structure I got from parsing the JSON request with the following command: `request_data=json.loads(request.POST['request'])`

```
{
    u'userID': u'123', 
    u'actions': {
        u'1': {u'notes': u'actionID= 35', u'actionType': u'7', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'}, 
        u'0': {u'notes': u'bla bla', u'actionType': u'2', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'}, 
        u'3': {u'notes': u'actionID= 31', u'actionType': u'7', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'},  
        u'2': {u'notes': u'actionID= 14', u'actionType': u'7', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'}, 
        u'5': {u'notes': u'actionID= 12', u'actionType': u'7', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'}
    }
}
```

when i try looping on it how can I get to the notes and action type

```
counter=0
for key in user_actions:
   value=user_actions[str(counter)]
   #how can I extract notes out of value???                  
   counter = counter +1
```

I've tried:

- value.notes
- value['notes']
- user_actions[key]['notes']

It makes no sense to me cause if I print `value` i get the inner dictionary `{u'notes': u'actionID= 35', u'actionType': u'7', u'currentTime': u'26/08/14'}` but using the same logic to extract the inner dictionary values does not work

Comment: That's not JSON, it's Python repr(), so of course it won't parse as JSON.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - this is the result i get from request_data=json.loads(request.POST['request']) --> how do I extract the notes from Python repr()?

Comment: Ahh -- so you're not showing us the JSON request, you're showing us the Python structure you got from the parsing the JSON. That makes sense. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks I've edited the question with your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for k, v in user_actions.iteritems():
    print v['notes']
```

Comment: Thanks it works!!!!
I have to wait 5 minutes until I can accept your answer but I will :)